# GET request inside of a loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, get

So, my code looks something like

```
for(int n = 0; n < object.length; n++){
  /*Other code */
  $.get(...,function(data){
    //do stuff
  });}
```

Now, the other code executes multiple times like it should. However, when the get command is ran, it is only ran once and that is when n reaches the object.length. This causes all sorts of errors. n is only being incremented in the for loop.

Can you not loop get/post commands? Or if you can, what am doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The for-loop won't wait for the `$.get` call to finish so you need to add some async flow control around this.

Check out [async.eachSeries](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachSeries). The `done` callback below is the key to controlling the loop. After the success/fail of each `$.get` request you call `done();` (or if there's an error, you call `done(someErr);`). This will advance the array iterator and move to the next item in the loop.

```
var async = require("async");
var list = ["foo", "bar", "qux"];

async.eachSeries(list, function(item, done) {

  // perform a GET request for each item in the list
  // GET url?somevar=foo
  // GET url?somevar=bar
  // GET url?somevar=qux
  $.get(url, {somevar: item}, function(data) {
    // do stuff, then call done
    done();
  });

}, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  console.log("All requests are done");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you want all the get requests to be done at the same time or one after the other?
You can do all at once with a forEach loop. forEach works better than a normal for loop because it gives you a new instance of `elem` and `n` in each iteration.

```
object.forEach(function(elem, n) {
  /*Other code */
  $.get(...,function(data){
    //do stuff
  });
});
```

But if you want to do the requests one after the other you could do it this way.

```
(function loop(n) {
  if(n >= object.length) return;
  /*Other code */
  $.get(...,function(data){
      //do stuff
      loop(n + 1);
    });
})(0);
```